# Get link text and href and wrap it in other html tags

Tags: regex, replace

How can stuff like this:

```
<b><a class='visit' href='LINK'>LINK'S NAME</a></b>
```

Can be turned into this:

`<tr><td>LINK'S NAME<а href="LINK">constant text</a></td></tr>`

Comment: [The pony he comes...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/554546)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **never use regex for HTML manipulation**, unless you have a good reason to do so.

---

*regex for match:*

`/<b>\s*<a\s+class='visit'\s+href='([^']*)'\s*>([^<]+)<\/a>\s*<\/b>/`

*replacemenet:*

`"<tr><td>$2<а href=\"$1\">constant text</a></td></tr>"`

Comment: Can you tell me why I shouldn't use regex for HTML manipulation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454